# How to load a python module into a fresh interactive shell in Komodo?

Tags: python, shell, interpreter, komodo

When using PyWin I can easily load a python file into a fresh interactive shell and I find this quite handy for prototyping and other exploratory tasks.

I would like to use Komodo as my python editor, but I haven't found a replacement for PyWin's ability to restart the shell and reload the current module.   How can I do this in Komodo?

It is also very important to me that when I reload I get a fresh shell.  I would prefer it if my previous interactions are in the shell history, but it is more important to me that the memory be isolated from the previous versions and attempts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Komodo Edit, which might be a little less sophisticated than full Komodo.

I create a "New Command" with `%(python) -i %f` as the text of the command.  I have this run in a "New Console".  I usually have the starting directory as %p, the top of the project directory.

The -i option runs the file and drops into interactive Python.

Comment: Thanks, I tweaked some of the parameters but I think this will do nicely.